# Blender FBX/OBJ house export doesn't include interior

Tags: modeling, objects, export

I'm not exactly sure how to be able to render this house mode *with* the interior for use in Twinmotion. I can look 'inside' the house in Blender and see materials/faces/etc, but but it goes into twin motion, going into the house doesn't show the blackface of the walls etc (like no-clipping mode).

[image: In Twinmotion]

This is it in Blender:
[image: In Blender]

I'm not sure how to add a .blend file here (any suggestions)? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Joel! Just upload it here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and add the link to your question.

Comment: How do I add it here? It's not giving me a link. It's just sitting saying 'Files may take some time to process' but it's been quite a long time. Does it just take a *really* long time?

Comment: Usually not. It should go pretty quickly. Once it's uploaded the website will provide you a share-link.

Comment: Are the walls just flat planes? If so, maybe try using a solidify modifier

Comment: I'll take a look when I get back. :)

Comment: Yep. That did it. I thought the *walls* had thickness, but it was the baseboard wrapper that had thickness. Setting a solidify modifier fixed it. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

stphnl329 was right. I can't believe I didn't notice it, but the main exterior walls (which are hard to make out in wireframe) are just planes of no thickness. I added a solidify modifier and applied it, and all is well! Thanks!